# Build command is not running in GitBash

Tags: command, git-bash, simulator

Build command is failing when running below,

mingw32-make build
Note: Installing lorawan simulator for testing.

1. Copied files/binaries from Git hub
2. Using the steps given in the attached Readme File

[image]

build to be succeed.